# Planet API Quick-Search returns areas way larger than what I'm requesting

Tags: python, polygon, geojson, features, planet

I'm following [this](https://github.com/planetlabs/notebooks/blob/master/jupyter-notebooks/data-api-tutorials/search_and_download_quickstart.ipynb) tutorial to search and download images with Planet API, problem is the features I get when I perform a quick-search have coordinates of an area several times larger than the area I include in my request, here are two comparative images of the area I request and the one I get in geojson.io.

[image: Area I get vs area I requested]

This is the json I'm sending in the search request:

```
{
  "item_types": [
    "PSScene"
  ],
  "filter": {
    "type": "AndFilter",
    "config": [
      {
        "type": "GeometryFilter",
        "field_name": "geometry",
        "config": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                -61.927174,
                -29.863805
              ],
              [
                -61.927174,
                -29.856375
              ],
              [
                -61.914071,
                -29.856375
              ],
              [
                -61.914071,
                -29.863805
              ],
              [
                -61.927174,
                -29.863805
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "DateRangeFilter",
        "field_name": "acquired",
        "config": {
          "gte": "2023-10-20T00:00:00Z",
          "lte": "2023-10-25T00:00:00Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notebook does the following, as mentioned above initialization of the `geometry_filter`: `# get images that overlap with our AOI`.

This means that you will receive the IDs of any *full* PSScene images (one satellite shot) that overlap with or fully contain the specified AOI and additionally fit the other filter criteria you have specified (in the example notebook: cloud cover and date range). Check out the [item type](https://developers.planet.com/docs/data/planetscope/#item-types) description in the PlanetScope documentation; it also helps to visualize the PSScene images overlapping with your AOI in the Planet Explorer (if your plan allows it).

The main purpose of the Data API demonstrated in the notebook is to find image IDs that fit the criteria specified. For the actual download, other APIs are better suited, e.g., the [Orders API](https://developers.planet.com/apis/orders/). The Orders API offers the [`clip`](https://developers.planet.com/apis/orders/tools/#clip) and [`composite`](https://developers.planet.com/apis/orders/tools/#composite) tools which together clip the full scene image to only the AOI specified and reduce overlap between multiple scene images in your order to just one image (that is, if grouped by `order`; else one image per `strip_id`, i.e., a "continuous line scan" by the satellite which itself contains overlap, see PlanetScope docs).

The exact details depend on your plan (e.g., the difference between "preferred" and "premium" clipping); see also the [Orders API FAQ](https://support.planet.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011216618-Orders-API-FAQ).

Not getting into the Subscriptions API as I'm not too familiar with it but it seems to offer similar functionality (see [Subscriptions API FAQ](https://support.planet.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013813737-Subscriptions-API-FAQs)).